# Kinect for Xbox Compatiable with OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni, xbox, point-cloud-library

I am using the Kinect for Xbox and I am planning on using the OpenNI framework along with the Point Cloud Library for processing but I am having trouble getting OpenNI to recognize my Kinect for Xbox and I wanted to make sure that it is actually compatible with the device.

For some reason I haven't been able to find any documentation on this exact topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCL does indeed work with OpenNI. I've managed to easily compile the [OpenNI Grabber Sample](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber) on Windows (using the All In One installer). I must admit I haven't managed the same on osx (had some issues with various versions of VTK being installed on the machine).

By the looks of it the issue doesn't look like it's on the PCL side, but on the OpenNI driver side. Can you run any of the samples ? If not, what error messages are you getting ?
I recommend cleaning up (uninstalling OpenNI, NITE, SensorKinect) and installing the unstable versions, but try installing in this order:

1. OpenNI 1.5.4.0
2. Nite 1.5.2.21
3. [Avin's SensorKinect](https://github.com/avin2/sensorkinect)

Comment: sorry I missed an important detail.  I am running it on Linux and I feel like that has something to do with it

Comment: I haven't tried on Linux myself, but I'm pretty sure it works. AFAIK most people doing PCL development and use Kinects do so on Linux with OpenNI. On a quick [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=openni+linux+setup&aq=f&oq=openni+linux+setup&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) I've found plenty of setup guides: [**1**](http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-kinect-openni-primesense/),[**2**](http://www.kdab.com/setting-up-kinect-for-programming-in-linux-part-1/),[**3**](http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-install-kin-in-linux-mint-12-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of OpenNI that you use?
If you use version 1.5.4, I think there is no problem because OpenNI interact directly with your Kinect Xbox.
However, if you use OpenNI version 2.x, it will interact with your device via Kinect SDK (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/a11ff6d9-7fbe-4636-8ff0-92d6220ac3f8/) Since there is no Kinect SDK on linux, you can't make OpenNI 2 to recognize your device.